# ubuntu 20.04 is slow on showing the password input after standby

Tags: gnome, keyboard

I got a new Dell precision 3470 with Ubuntu 20.04. I noticed that on the login page after I clicked with the mouse or pressed a button, the password input appear with a delay of some seconds. How can I reduce this time?

Running the command `journalctl -ae --full`,
I get the following:

```
dic 21 17:30:53 Dell-Ale NetworkManager[1233]: <info>  [1671640253.2344] agent-manager: agent[086884b93e5e18ff,:1.92/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1001]: agent registered
dic 21 17:30:53 Dell-Ale gnome-shell[2688]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
dic 21 17:30:53 Dell-Ale gnome-shell[2688]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
dic 21 17:30:53 Dell-Ale gnome-shell[2688]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
dic 21 17:30:53 Dell-Ale gnome-shell[2688]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
dic 21 17:30:53 Dell-Ale gnome-shell[2688]: cr_parser_new_from_buf: assertion 'a_buf && a_len' failed
dic 21 17:30:53 Dell-Ale gnome-shell[2688]: cr_declaration_parse_list_from_buf: assertion 'parser' failed
dic 21 17:30:53 Dell-Ale gnome-shell[2688]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 31 with keysym 31 (keycode a).
dic 21 17:30:53 Dell-Ale gnome-shell[2688]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 32 with keysym 32 (keycode b).
dic 21 17:30:53 Dell-Ale gnome-shell[2688]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 34 with keysym 34 (keycode d).
dic 21 17:30:53 Dell-Ale gnome-shell[2688]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 33 with keysym 33 (keycode c).
dic 21 17:30:53 Dell-Ale gnome-shell[2688]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
dic 21 17:30:53 Dell-Ale gnome-shell[2688]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 39 with keysym 39 (keycode 12).
dic 21 17:30:53 Dell-Ale gnome-shell[2688]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 35 with keysym 35 (keycode e).
dic 21 17:30:53 Dell-Ale gnome-shell[2688]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 36 with keysym 36 (keycode f).
dic 21 17:30:53 Dell-Ale gnome-shell[2688]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 37 with keysym 37 (keycode 10).
dic 21 17:30:56 Dell-Ale systemd[2457]: Started Application launched by gsd-media-keys.
dic 21 17:30:56 Dell-Ale dbus-daemon[2469]: [session uid=1001 pid=2469] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gnome.Terminal' unit='gnome-terminal-server.service' requested by ':1.211' (uid=1001 pid>
dic 21 17:30:56 Dell-Ale systemd[2457]: Starting GNOME Terminal Server...
dic 21 17:30:56 Dell-Ale dbus-daemon[2469]: [session uid=1001 pid=2469] Successfully activated service 'org.gnome.Terminal'
dic 21 17:30:56 Dell-Ale systemd[2457]: Started GNOME Terminal Server.
dic 21 17:30:56 Dell-Ale systemd[2457]: Started VTE child process 13790 launched by gnome-terminal-server process 13782.
dic 21 17:30:56 Dell-Ale systemd[2457]: gnome-launched-x-terminal-emulator-13776.scope: Succeeded.
```